# Append entry to end of linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I want to add an entry to a linked list at the end, but am having trouble dealing with pointers. Here's my linked list:

```
struct list {
    int val;
    list *next;
};
```

**I declare a list `aList` globally:**

```
struct list *aList;
```

**And have a function to add values to the list:**

```
void add(int var) {
    struct list *temp = aList;
    if (temp == NULL) { //if aList is empty
        temp = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
        temp->val = var; //add it to first spot
        temp->next = NULL;
    } else { //if aList is not empty
        while (temp->next != NULL) { //find the first empty spot
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
        temp->val = var; //add it to empty spot
        temp->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

I'm really lost with the pointers. I want to add to `aList` so I need to make a temp list pointing to it and add to that (any changes reflect on `aList`). Without using a temp list, I lose the structure of the list and it will contain 1 or 0 elements irrespective of how many I've added.

**Say I want to do the below:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { add(i); }
```

I want `aList` to be `1->2->3->4->5->NULL` and be able to access it starting from `1`.

Comment: It's way easier to add stuff to the beginning of the linked list. Just set the new one's "next" pointer to the head of list, and set the head of list aList to the new one.

Comment: @PaulTomblin Even then, I need to add the first value, and `temp` is not NULL even with zero elements.

Comment: Your `add` method will store the `malloc` result to a local variable `temp`, so `aList` is never updated. `temp` doesn't point to `aList`, but to what `aList` points to. Change the `then` part of your if to use `aList` only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (temp->next != NULL) { //find the first empty spot
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
```

You're overwriting the last element when you do this.

Instead, you need to assign it to a new node.

```
struct list *newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
// Fill newnode
temp->next = newnode;
```

Comment: or `temp->next = malloc(sizeof(struct list)); temp=temp->next;`